# what is a subsequential limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I find the subsequential limits of the sequence $s_n$ = $n^2[-1+(-1)^n]$

I know that $[-1+(-1)^n]$ is either -2 if n is odd or 0 if n is even and so $s_n$ = $-2n^2$ if n is odd and $s_n$ = 0 if n is even. And I also know what does a subsequence means and so a subsequential limit is the limit of the subsequence of $s_n$ but how to get the subsequences of $s_n$ in the first place?

Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To find the subsequential limits, you can actually look at the problem as finding all the limit points of the sequence $\{s_n\}$. You don't need to define the actual subsequences.

Side note with this notation: Let $D$ denote the set of all limit points  (allowing $\pm \infty$) of any sequence $\{s_n\}$, if 
$$\sup D = \inf D = s,$$
then $s_n$ converges to $s$.